# Missing brackets error Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This is the command I'm trying to use but it says there are missing brackets. How do I fix it?

```
/summon Wolf ~ ~1 ~ {Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:99999},{Name:generic.followRange,Base:99999},{Name:generic.attackDamage,Base:10},{Name:generic.movementSpeed,Base:1}],ActiveEffects:[{Id:9,Amplifier:9999,Duration:9999,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:7,Amplifier:9999,Duration:9999,ShowParticles:0b},{Id:11,Amplifier:2,Duration:9999,ShowParticles:0b}]}
```

Comment: I don't know what version or edition you're using but all the brackets are in place and none are missing, and it definitely works in my command block if I make "Wolf" lowercase. I use Java Edition v1.13.2.

Comment: Try a shorter command, these super long ones are tedious to debug.

Comment: im using version 1.8.9